# Dart, Flutter; How to get color from MaterialStateProperty

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

Some values in a `Theme` object must be provided as `MaterialStateProperty<T>`, e.g. `backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white)`. How can the property of type `T` be accessed in a Flutter widget?

E.g. the following line produces an (obvious) error:

```
Container(color: Theme.of(context).elevatedButtonTheme.style?.backgroundColor)
```

```
Error: *The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty<Color?>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'*
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try

```
Container(color: Theme.of(context).elevatedButtonTheme.style!.backgroundColor!.resolve(Set.of[MaterialState.pressed]))
```

But you make to have sure that there is backgroundColor for this theme, otherwise you will get "Unexpected null value" exception.

Comment: elevatedButtonTheme.style!.backgroundColor!.resolve({MaterialState.pressed}))